# Composer failure when installing Laravel 5.8 + Voyager

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8, voyager

I installed laravel 5.8, and then i did `composer require tcg/voyager:1.3.2`. I didn't used `composer require tcg/voyager` cause apparently it doesn't supports laravel 5.8. However it keeps failling and throwing this problem:

```
Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.1.3, 1.0.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: league/flysystem[1.0.x-dev, 1.1.3].
    - tcg/voyager v1.3.2 requires league/flysystem ~1.0.41 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for tcg/voyager 1.3.2 -> satisfiable by tcg/voyager[v1.3.2].
    - Installation request for league/flysystem 1.1.3 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.3].
```

I tried first installing `composer require league/flysystem:1.1.3` before voyager but still it fails with the same error. Am at the lost here.

Comment: try composer update

Comment: @dqureshiumar Will that update my laravel framework? I need to use laravel 5.8

Comment: Okay Okay wait.

Comment: try installing composer require tcg/voyager:1.1.3

Comment: @dqureshiumar Same error

Comment: keep changing version @jogarcia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked whether `league/flysystem` has been installed before? According to that error message it is installed in v1.1.3, while `tcg/voyager` requires v1.0.* - this is not compatible.

v1.1 of the flysystem is pretty new, and only the current dev branches of Voyager contain fixes for this.

To resolve this situation, you could run `composer require league/flysystem:"~1.0.41"`